# Node js mongodb query

Tags: node.js

how can i convert the query to mongodb. SQL to Mongo Query. Help me please.

```
$query = "SELECT *,COUNT(*) as count FROM ip_table WHERE test = '1' GROUP BY ip_address ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT " . $start . "," . $limit;
```

I just couldn't add the "ORDER BY count DESC" part and set it

```
.aggregate([
    {
        $match: queries,
    },
    {
        $group: {
          _id: "$ip_address",
          count:{$sum:1}
        },
        {
            $sort:{"count":-1}
          }
    },
])
.skip(start)
.limit(limitQuery)
```

Fixed thank you...

Comment: Warning! You are open to SQL Injection attacks! What if the first variable is `; DROP TABLE ip_table; --`

Comment: We are not a code conversion service. See [ask]

Comment: edit question  @esqew

Comment: Please review [ask] and edit your question to conform by including what you *expect* to happen with the code provided, and what *actually* happens.

Comment: If you figured it out, then submit an answer documenting your solution. (Scroll down and press `Answer Your Question`)